# Log Structured Merge-tree vs Merkle tree

Tags: cassandra, hbase, riak, nosql

I have seen these both trees being very famous in No SQL implementations. Cassandra uses Merkle Tree and HBase uses LSM Tree.

Though they might not work exactly same, is there any clear details on which one is a good in what.?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra uses LSM trees as well. Cassandra only uses merkle trees to hash the data set and compare node's data during repairs.